# Hibernate manytomany object filter

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I am a newbie in Java and am stuck in a simple problem. I have a class named UserProfile and another named Company. Both are related by ManyToMany relation. Their definitions are as follows:

```
// User Profile
@Entity
@Table(name="SEC_USER_PROFILES") 
@JsonSerialize(using=UserSerializer.class)
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{
    Long userId;
    .
    ...

    private List<Company> companiesList;


    public UserProfile() {
        this.companiesList = new ArrayList<Company>();
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="SEC_USERS_COMPANIES",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USERID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMPANYID")
            )
    //@JsonIgnore
    public List<Company> getCompaniesList() {
        return companiesList;
    }
    public void setCompaniesList(List<Company> companies) {
        this.companiesList = companies;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    // other getters and setters
}
```

And the Company class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SEC_COMPANIES")
public class Company implements Serializable{
    Long companyId;
    String companyName;
    String companyAddress;
    String companyDesc;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "COMPANYID") 
    public Long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }
    public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }
    // other getters setters
}
```

And now I need to filter userprofiles with companyId=3 and other criteria like firstName="John" and so on. I did not see any obvious solution using criteria. You need not worry about any other underlying implementations and setup. I just want a way to filter userprofile in an easy way.
How can I achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: You need a join: `select u from UserProfile u join u.companiesList c where u.firstName = 'John' and c.companyId = 3`.

Comment: is it not possible without writing such query? I mean, by using criteria.

Comment: Yes, you can use criteria. You will also need a join. I don't know if you're talking about the Hibernate proprietary criteria API or about the standard JPA criteria API. In both cases, you just need to translate the above JPQL query.

Comment: okay, thanks. I will try..